# Matlabfrag figure in latex

Tags: eps, matlab, psfrag, pstool

I have been trying to figure out the best way to include vector plots from Matlab in Latex. I rounded on to `matlabfrag`, which is relatively straight forward compared to `matlab2tikz`.

Somehow, I am not even able to reproduce a basic example. I followed the `matlabfrag` example from [here](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/matlabandlatex.html). In Matlab,

```
plot(1:10) ; title('help')
matlabfrag('fragtest')
```

foo.tex :

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{pstool}
   \begin{document}
   \psfragfig{fragtest}
   \end{document}
```

Compiled with:    `pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex`. On compilation, I get a blank document with following message:
[image]

As suggested, I looked into the `fragtest-pstool.log` file and it contained the following errors:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   e
l.22  \includegraphics [] {fragtest}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   e
l.22  \includegraphics [] {fragtest}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

I searched regarding this error with respect to `psfragfig`, but could not find any relevant solution. The similar problem is faced and report by someone [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/6VBsK8Man00) [in German]. But they do not mention the solution explicitly. Can someone help me on this? I spent the last two days completely on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a tested solution, but just the translation of an answer on de.comp.text.tex to a similar problem (at least generating the same error).

> The error is generated by `matlabfrag-pstool.tex`: Font sizes are given in exponential notation, which is not acceptable to LaTeX. The is the result of an error in the `matlab` code, which I have corrected and mailed to the author. [[Matthias Pospiech, 10 Oct 2010](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/de.comp.text.tex/6VBsK8Man00/SAMF7gqz4N8J)]

Try to download the latest version of `matlabfrag` from https://github.com/zprime/matlabfrag (v0.7.0devb04 30-May-2013). At the other download sites that I found `matlabfrag` is older than the posting above, so doesn't contain the bug fix (if it was fixed indeed).

Comment: True. Inside the `tex` file related with the `eps` file, there was line with `\fontsize{1.320000e+01}{1.320000e+01}`, which is an invalid `Latex` unit. Therefore, modifying the font size to an integer or latex valid unit solved the issue.